# Android - Facebook Login - Obtain Authentication token

Tags: android, facebook

I've implemented Facebook Login on my app following official docs, so with official Facebook SDK.

Other people worked on iOS app with official Facebook SDK.

At the end of the login process, we correctly obtained access token, but ios SDK gave them also an authentication token, which is a JWT token.

In fact, in iOS there id the FBSDKAuthenticationToken class, while in Android nothing similar is available.

How can i obtain the authentication token in Android?

I'm not adding pieces of code, since i exactly followed docs, but if you need it please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The OIDC token is part of [Limited Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login), and it appears that is currently available for iOS and Unity only, but not for Android.

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much! I missed that part of the docs. At the end i managed to obtain it using facebook login through Firebase or Auth0.